# Xamarin - Compile AOT in Community edition?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, obfuscation

I wanted to obfuscate my application, but I couldn't find a free obfuscator for commercial use. I saw that mono supports AOT compilation, so is there a was to compile my app ahead of time using the community version of Xamarin?

If not: is there a free obfuscator for C#(xamarin) for commercial use?

NOTE:
I'm targeting Android

Comment: Why is your question about compiling AOT if you are asking about Obfuscation as well?

Comment: @JonDouglas Because if it's not possible in the community edition, then I want to know if there's a free obfuscator for commercial use.

Answer (score 4):

I want to clarify the licensing restrictions that come with Dotfuscator Community Edition (CE). UUioP writes "*I know about Dotfuscator, but I was actually looking for a free obfuscator for commercial use.*" Dotfuscator CE most certainly comes with license restrictions that preclude *most* commercial use scenarios, but there is one exception (granted - it is a very narrow exception, but one that might work for some). Dotfuscator CE can be used to release commercial software if the code being obfuscated is written and owned by the Dotfuscator CE user. In other words, if you develop your own app (and it's your app - not your employer's), you can use Dotfuscator CE to obfuscate your app - even if it is for sale or other "commercial/production" use. See [(Re) Introducing Dotfuscator CE](https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/894-re-introducing-dotfuscator-community-edition/91-dotfuscator-ce) - the licensing terms are explained towards the end of the post.

Comment: I am using some libraries, so Dotfuscator is not an option for me.

Comment: Why would your use of libraries exclude Dotfuscator? Since you've replied to my comment - can I assume that this is a licensing issue from your perspective? Assuming yes, if the 3rd party who wrote the library is asking you to obfuscate their library to better secure their code, then yes, you are correct - that is not the intent of the CE license. If you want to obfuscate your code that calls those libraries - and you don't obfuscate their code - only your code - that would be permitted with CE.

Comment: Now, I know this is na old question, but I did NOT know about this detail. Does that mean "indie" developer can use Preemptive's Dotfuscator without restrictions, as far as the code they're writing is theirs?

Answer (score 3):

> The AOT Compilation option requires an Enterprise license or higher. AOT compilation is available only when the project is configured for Release mode, and it is disabled by default.

**Source:** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#AOT_Compilation

As for obfuscation, Xamarin.Android does not support obfuscation out of the box. You will need to use a third party obfuscation tool like [Dotfuscator](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview). They have a tutorial on this [here](https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/874-using-dotfuscator-community-edition-with-xamarin/91-dotfuscator-ce).

Many people think `Proguard` will obfuscate their code in a Xamarin.Android project, but it only works on the Java end.

> The Xamarin.Android ProGuard configuration does not obfuscate the APK, and it is not possible to enable obfuscation through ProGuard, even with custom configuration files. If you wish to use obfuscation, please see [Application Protection with Dotfuscator](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#dotfuscator).

**Source:**
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#ProGuard

Comment: So it's not possible with the community edition although mono supports AOT?

Comment: I know about Dotfuscator, but I was actually looking for a free obfuscator for **commercial** use.

Answer (score 2):

**AOT in Xamarin:**

It depends whether you are targeting Android or iOS.

As @Jon Douglas states in his answer, **Android** AOT in Xamarin is unfortunately currently limited to Enterprise licenses.  (tip: You can test out this Enterprise feature using a limited-time Enterprise license trial.)

**iOS** AOT in Xamarin, on the other hand, is part of every iOS build, so you get it with the Community license for free.  Note however, that the full .Net assemblies are still included in iOS release builds, so that defeats the purpose of AOT "obfuscation" in iOS. :/

**Obfuscation:**

ConfuserEx is a great .Net open-source obfuscator with an MIT License:

https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/

I still haven't tested ConfuserEx end-to-end in a Xamarin app, but it looks promising so far...  (Beware, as many people point out, ConfuserEx is a little "confusing" to use...)

Comment: I am targeting Android, I'll mention it in my answer.